# Get CakePHP input names using javascript

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I need to know if there are some way using JavaScript to get an input element by name, like the CakePHP names, something like `Details[0][color]`, I just need to know if is possible or it is necessary to use and input id in this case.

Comment: HOw ?, becouse I need to use something like  document.forms[0].FieldName.value;  but using that name, I can't use getElementsByName becouse the devices are so old and looks to me like do not support it, it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to write a [better question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). First: you haven't tried anything, or maybe you did but you didn't tell us. Add what have you tried and why didn't it work to your question. You say you can't use ´getElementsByName´, then what can you use? what are the requirements? cakephp uses jquery, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean get by `name` property, using jquery you can:

```
 $('[name="TheName"]')
```

If you want to use plain javascript you can use

```
document.getElementsByName()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName